# How to migrate primeng p-dataTable to p-table?

Tags: primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-turbotable

We are planning to migrate primeng to the latest version. Currently we have p-dataTable implemented. What would be the better approach to migrate p-dataTable to p-table? -->
1. Implement p-table from scratch? OR
2. we have any option to migrtate(with minimal changes to exisiting code)?
I am new to primeng and I didnt find much information on this. Please correct me if I am wrong at any point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no 'migration' guide . Those two are quite different. Even selection is working differently. You will most likely have to just rewrite table related code.
reference :
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table